# Android - Restlet

Tags: java, android, rest, frameworks

I'm trying to use [this](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/275-restlet/266-restlet/269-restlet.html) tutorial on Restlet for Android, and can't get the sample application, linked to at the bottom of my link's page to run.

There are major issues in a file called `IContactService.java`, located at `/src/org.restlet.example.android.service`, but the file has the following header, so I'm not sure how to resolve them:

```
/*
 * This file is auto-generated.  DO NOT MODIFY.
 * Original file: /mnt/sda5/data/workspace/android/androidRestlet/src/org/restlet/example/android/service/IContactService.aidl
 */
```

Does anyone have any experience getting Restlet to work with Android? Or, are there any better frameworks / tutorials out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this REST client instead, I've used it a lot - by far the best one for Android development.

http://www.springsource.org/spring-android

Comment: Actually, I can't get the download to start. I tried filling out the form, and skipping it, and it keeps giving me a null hyperlink to spring%20android. Thoughts?

Comment: nevermind, found it elsewhere on the site. Is there anything special I need to do / know to use this? Or do I just import a jar and start programming?

Comment: Just import the jar and go from there.

Comment: @j0ntech Your link seems dead.

Comment: The one in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late response, I also had problems with the tutorial you mentioned, so my approach was to start with a basic Android tutorial (actually from a printed book - Apress's Beginning Android 4 and then I was able to incorporate the Restlet parts by following Manning's Restlet in Action (available as a PDF now with the printed copy coming in a few months).  I have "something" "working" now :).

RB

Answer (score 0):

Use [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/downloads/stable) framework, it has "Edition for Android" version.